# Installed Anaconda for pylab, but still can't import pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

Oh I am trying to import pylab for 4 hours now, but still really in need of help.

I use python 2.7.10.
While learning plotting, the prof typed "import pylab as plot", "plt.plot(data1, data2)", then a graph appeared.

However when I did, I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/MARISSA/Documents/문제별 알고리즘/L13/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
import pylab as plt
File "/Users/MARISSA/Documents/문제별 알고리즘/L13/pylab.py", line 16, in <module>
plt.plot(mySamples, myLinear)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

So I installed anaconda graphical installer from [here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

and tried in terminal

```
sudo easy_install matplotlib
```

then only got

```
Searching for matplotlib
Best match: matplotlib 2.0.0
Adding matplotlib 2.0.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /Users/MARISSA/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Processing dependencies for matplotlib
Finished processing dependencies for matplotlib
```

however still get the same error above.

I am new to programming, please be kind enough to explain for me. Thanks!

Comment: Your script is named `pylab.py`. This is a problem. Try renaming it.

Comment: I deleted the script and tried again. Just the same :(

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your import statement with:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plot
```

This will load the pylab module from the matplotlib library. See http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but still got ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot ...

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the matplotlib install. Without knowing more about your Linux distro, the best I can suggest is to follow the instructions on matplotlib's [Installing](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html) page to see if that fixes your installation.

Comment: Thanks!! I deleted and reinstalled, and solved problems :)